# Como mejorar el codigo para que no haya repeticion

Tags: javascript

He creado un password generator App. Y como veran a continuacion en el codigo, dentro de la funcion, repito cuatro veces el mismo procedimiento, para poder generar 4 contraseñas haciendo un solo click, y guardando las mismas en 4 variables distiantas, las cuales van a ser impresas en 4 inputs.

Mi objetivo es no repetir el codigo esta cantidad de veces, hacerlo mas conciso y ajustarlo a las buenas practicas.

Obviamente se me ha ocurrido usar un loop, pero no logro entender como crear 4 variables distintas ( Si es que realmente necesito crearlas, para poder luego hacer el display de las contraseñas en el input.)

```
const letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const numbers = "0123456789";
const symbols = "!@#$%^&*_-+=";


const button = document.querySelector(".gen-pass");

const input1 = document.querySelector(".first-password")
const input2 = document.querySelector(".second-password")
const input3 = document.querySelector(".third-password")
const input4 = document.querySelector(".fourth-password")

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();

  const password = Array(4).fill(0).flatMap(() => 
  [
      letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)],
      numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)],
      symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)]
    ]
  ).join('');

  const password2 = Array(4).fill(0).flatMap(() => 
    [
      letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)],
      numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)],
      symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)]
    ]
  ).join('');

  const password3 = Array(4).fill(0).flatMap(() => 
    [
      letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)],
      numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)],
      symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)]
    ]
  ).join('');

  const password4 = Array(4).fill(0).flatMap(() => 
    [
      letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)],
      numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)],
      symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)]
    ]
  ).join('');

    input1.value = password;        
    input2.value = password2;        
    input3.value = password3;        
    input4.value = password4;        
    
})
```

Comment: Un método que haga esto mismo y retorne el string. Cada vez que lo llames debería entregar un string diferente :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como lo indica un comentario, la mejor forma de evitar la repeticion seria creando una funcion con la logica que necesitas.  Algo asi:

```js
const letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const numbers = "0123456789";
const symbols = "!@#$%^&*_-+=";

const password = function() {
  return Array(4).fill(0).flatMap(() => 
  [
      letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)],
      numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)],
      symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)]
    ]
  ).join('');
}


const button = document.querySelector(".gen-pass");

const input1 = document.querySelector(".first-password")
const input2 = document.querySelector(".second-password")
const input3 = document.querySelector(".third-password")
const input4 = document.querySelector(".fourth-password")

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
 
    input1.value = password();        
    input2.value = password();         
    input3.value = password();       
    input4.value = password();         
    
})
```

```html
<input class="first-password" >
<input class="second-password" >
<input class="third-password" >
<input class="fourth-password" >
<button class="gen-pass" >gen</button>
```